# Get unicode csv strings from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, unicode

I have a pandas dataframe, and I want an iterable of unicode csv strings.
`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()` gives a bytestring, but I want a unicode string. Should I do `df.to_csv(encoding='utf-8').decode('utf-8')`  or `unicodecsv.DictWriter` to `io.StringIO`, over all of the rows in `df.iterrows()`, or another option? I'm working in Python 2.7.

Comment: How did you deal with that?